# c# ftp client retry delay

Tags: c#, ftp

i was able to create a basic ftp client that is working, but i want to make it more robust.  one of the features i want to add is retry delay (The time between each retry).  unfortunately i couldn't find a lot of materials online.  can someone help me?  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) ?

> `Thread.Sleep` Method
>
> Blocks the current thread for the specified number of milliseconds.